# Razor intellisense doesn't consider inherited properties

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm using RazorEngine 3 (Antaris fork at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) for generating emails from Razor views, and have a 'base' view class that extends `TemplateBase<T>` called `EmailTemplateBase<T>`.

The web.config in the **Views** directory has the base type properly set:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="EmailTemplateBase`1[[EmailModelBase]]">
        ...
```

I can also confirm, after restarting Visual Studio (2012) that the properties defined on `EmailTemplateBase<T>` are accessible through IntelliSense. The problem is that the public properties defined on its base class (TemplateBase), particularly `_Layout` and `Model` are inaccessible through IntelliSense.

Replicating these properties in `EmailTemplateBase<T>` works:

```
public new T Model
{
    get { return base.Model; }
    set { base.Model = value; }
}
```

However, I shouldn't have to do this. Surely there must be a better way? Why can't Visual Studio's Razor code editor see the properties on my base class?

Comment: The Razor intellisense experience is far from perfect even in VS2012. So if a base property doesn't show up but your page compiles and works in runtime don't sweat on it. Maybe you open a Microsoft connect issue...